# How do i stop my untrainable puppies from chewing on plush toy?

Tags: dogs, behavior

I am 12 and my favorite plush yoshi started getting chewed on.
The puppies are 2-3 months old and we havent been able to train them at all.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you're not going to get a 2-3 month-old puppy to not chew things.

It's a phase that they all go through. Human babies go through it as well. We call it "teething" and we have many safe things that we give our babies to gnaw.

What you're going to need to do is, firstly, make sure they can't get to your toys. Second, get toys that they may chew. These are easy to find at pet shops, vets, or many supermarkets. If you find them chewing something they should not, take it away and replace it with something that they may.

Do not scold, spank, or reprimand them in any way. It won't help and you'll end up with fearful puppies.

2-3 months is very young for a puppy. I would not expect a puppy of that age to be trained. It takes time to train them. Patience and consistency are key.

I have a book which I have used to train many puppies. It is Complete Puppy School, by Dr. Quixi Sonntag ([https://www.amazon.com/Complete-Puppy-School-quixi-sonntag/dp/1845371739](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1845371739)). I would recommend that you get a copy and work through it. You and your puppies will learn a lot from it. If you can't get your own copy, you could look for it at your local library, or you could look for other puppy training books at the library, second-hand book stores, etc, or find a puppy training web-site. Or, come chat to us in The Litter Box.

There's no such thing as an untrainable puppy. Some just take more patience than others.

Comment: Just to be clear, the only training that you can do at this phase is yourself! Learn to put things away or your puppy will get into it.